# Existence of common basis where matrix are diagonalized.

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider set of linear operators $\{A_{i} \}$. We have that $A_{i}A_{j}v = A_{j}A_{i}v$, $\forall v \in V$. And also we know that one matrix is diagonalized. Is it true that there is exist basis where all matrix are diagonalized?

I could prove that there is common eigenvector. But that doesn't give me any help. Any ideas?

Comment: Are the diagonal elements all different?

Answer (score 0):

Two matrices can be simultaneously diagonalized if and only if they commute. First, show that if two matrices commute in one basis, then they commute in any basis, then show that is two matrices are simultaneously diagonalized they commute.

Comment: But is it true for more than two matrices ?

Comment: And I know that they are commute